# Linq to SQL searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a table with users. I want to be able to search for a string and then return all username which contains this string. Then i want to populate a ListBox. This is what I have tried:

```
var varUser = (from u in dc.Users
                           where u.username == searchUserName
                           select u.username);
            lbSearchResult.DataSource = varUser;
            lbSearchResult.DataBind();
```

But when i try to search for "a" i don't get any results. It only works if i enter the full username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641.aspx) instead:

```
var varUser = from u in dc.Users
              where u.username.Contains(searchUserName)
              select u.username;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it can be case ignorant with `u.user.ToLower().Contains(searchUserName.ToLower())`

Comment: @ThePower `Contains` within LINQ-SQL will generate a `LIKE` statement that is case insensitive by default in MSSQL unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because of the clause

```
where u.username == searchUserName
```

Try `u.username.Contains(searchUserName)` or build a regular expression.